# Why is a pentode tube more power efficient than a triode tube?

Tags: tube, vacuum

As title.

I read some article and it says something like this:

- Tetrode was invented to reduce grid-plate capacitance.
- Pentode was invented to reduce secondary emission.

I also heard that a pentode has greater power efficiency than a triode.

I would like to know the principle and mechanism behind this.

Comment: [Here's some discussion](https://www.vintage-radio.net/forum/showthread.php?p=448420) about some differences. A pentode can also be more noisy. But that's a separate discussion.

Comment: 'I also heard ...' doesn't give the context of the assertion. Maybe better power efficiency than a triode at some given level of distortion, or for wideband use.

Comment: @Neil_UK maybe it would be better if I say "it is said that..."

Comment: @Moses No, that's just a different way to say 'I'm not going to show you the context of that remark'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tetrode was a remarkable invention, because its screen grid removed a great part of the next weakness of the triode (a Wikipedia image):

[image: Graph showing triode operating characteristic for different values of V_g]

You see that the plate current Ia depends on grid voltage and also heavily on the voltage between the plate and the cathode. The latter is not wanted: tube users want the grid voltage to control the plate current like in a theoretical dependent current source. A tetrode is closer to the desired operation, but secondary emission partially spoiled the function. The third (=the suppressor) grid in the pentode made the curves much more ideal:

[image]

The curves are captured from the EL84 datasheet (see NOTE1). The full explanation is available for ex. here: https://www.electroniclinic.com/pentode-construction-and-characteristics-in-electronics/

About the power efficiency: the non-horizontal Ia vs Ua curves mean effectively there's a parallel resistance inside the triode. It dissipates a part of the AC signal power like a real resistor. The pentode is not fully free of it, but with sufficient anode voltage Ua the Ia curves are much more horizontal than for the triode. That makes the pentode dissipate much less power for a certain AC output signal power.

NOTE1: There's still a little left of the same weakness as in tetrodes. When Ug1 =-10V and Ua is 10...20V Ia becomes lower as Ua increases. That's negative resistance. It can cause spurious oscillations in amplifiers if the operation is not kept out of that area. The tetrode has much more kinky Ia vs Ua curves at low Ua.

Comment: Notice in particular, you can use the tetrode down to say, 20V at 100mA, getting 280V of output swing from a 300V supply. If you tried the same with the triode you couldn't get the anode voltage below 100-150V, giving you only 150-200V swing from the same supply. That's where the practical efficiency loss comes from.

Comment: Nice summary, thanks.  Been a long time since I've had to think about things like triodes and pentodes <wink>.

Comment: Also re: Note 1 (and since the question asks about pentodes) - the pentode's suppressor grid (between screen grid and anode) is usually connected to the cathode to catch secondary emission electrons, and thus eliminate that kink. In (I believe) an attempt to evade the pentode patent, the "Kinkless Tetrode" was invented, where the suppressor grid was internally connected instead of brought out to a pin. Hence the famous "KT66" (compatible with the EL34 pentode) and later "KT88".

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, consider the load line:
[Load line and voltage or current gain](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/497940/load-line-and-voltage-or-current-gain) 
This example uses BJTs, but the graph plots the respective quantities.  Power output is proportional to the rectangle enclosing the load line: the longer and taller, the more power is available.

Triodes, in class 1 (no grid current) operation, have a rather limited active region, as you can see.  Incidentally, triodes have a pentode-like set of curves, extending for Vgk > 0*; but the grid is rarely rated to carry much current (and it will absorb a significant fraction of cathode current, being so close to it -- as well as the radiant cathode heat it's already taking, any additional dissipation is bad news!), so operation in this region is usually avoided.  (Exceptions are for pulsed operation, particularly of types rated for it like 5687 for instance, or transmitter tubes that are designed to handle the extra dissipation.)

*You can see just a taste of this on the 12AX7 already, how the Vgk = 0 curve ticks up slightly at the left edge.  The cathode has a small potential built in (pushed by thermal emission), effectively shifting it slightly into positive grid bias in this condition -- even though the external voltage (Vgk) is zero.  This is a small effect, so is only visible on small-signal triodes, like the 12AX7.  But it is indeed a real effect!

The effect of the screen grid, is to draw current flow as if grid voltage were elevated -- the cathode can "see" the screen's electric field through the grid (or rather, a fraction of it), thus mimicking the effect of positive grid voltage, but through a separate electrode.

Indeed, in the triode, the whole point is that the cathode can see a fraction of the plate voltage, which is why the plate curves are sloped significantly: roughly speaking, Ia is proportional to Vak.  So it would be great to be able to emulate this effect, having a virtual plate of sorts, but without intercepting all of the beam current -- and this is where the screen grid comes in.

There is another way to deal with secondary emission: space charge of the beam itself.  In suitably designed tubes, the intensity of the beam is enough to turn back secondary emission, thus reducing the "tetrode kink" that would otherwise result.  Usually beam-forming plates are used to do this (reducing the beam from a nearly-full cylinder to a narrower sector).

Beam tetrodes generally perform better than pentodes, due to having a sharper knee above saturation: pentodes generally have a broad arc to this part of the curve, which can cost a fair amount of available power.  (The curve also corresponds to increased screen current draw -- operating too low into saturation is likely to toaster-grid a pentode, but a tetrode doesn't mind.)

For an example of tetrode behavior, consider this old type:
https://frank.pocnet.net/sheets/049/2/24A.pdf 
As you can see, dipping below about 100V is not going to produce any real useful amplifying behavior.  Unless you want to operate fully in saturation, specifically to use it as a negative resistance oscillator or something.